# Kubernetes - delete pod after any container stops

Tags: azure, kubernetes, cloud, kubernetes-pod

I am deploying a pod with restartPolicy set to Never, which I was expecting would remove the pod if container dies. The only thing that happens is that the pod goes to NotReady state (as there is a side small container still running), but even if I kill that container it goes to Error state but stays around for a long period of time... How can I force kube to delete pod if container crashes?

Comment: By default, they won't be deleted on their own if failed, You will have to delete the crashed pods, OR you can have a `cronjob` to take care of cleaning every X minutes in your namespace/cluster. here is a discussion https://gist.github.com/zparnold/0e72d7d3563da2704b900e3b953a8229

Comment: Also, you can tweak this behavior by playing with garbage collection, see this  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-garbage-collection .

Answer (score 0):

Thank You [P....](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309601/p) for your suggestion adding few more points and posting this as solution to help other community member.

By default it won't delete the crash pods (cobtainer failed). You have to delete it manually.OR you can have a `cronjob` to take care of cleaning every X minutes in your namespace/cluster.

You can use this below kubectl command to delete the failed/crash pods fpr sepecific namespace.

```
kubectl --namespace=production get pods -a | grep Evicted | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl --namespace=production delete pod -o name
```

OR Inspite of deleting you can use [***Replication controller***](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/replicationcontroller/). If Pod created using RC will be automatically replaced if they does crash,failed or terminiated.

RC is recommanded if you just want to make sure pods is always running even after your system reboots.